# Firebase: retriving friend's data (Ionic Framework)

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where I need to fetch the user's friends geolocation data. What I need to do is:

1) loop the current user's node under "friends" node to get all of the user's friends

2) with that data, go loop "users/[[friend uid]]" for each friend and pull the lat and long from geolocation along with the friend's display name

This should be a subscribed event, as in if the geolocation updates in the server it should also show it in the app/update the variables.

Friends node structure is like this:

```
friends
    current user UID
        random id (not needed)
           friend 1 UID (needed)
        random id (not needed)
           friend 2 UID (needed)
        etc
```

Here's also a pic of the whole database structure:

[image: database]

Thank you!

Edit: here is the current code for retrieving friends, how could I implement getting the geolocation of each friend retrived?

```
friendsNode = firebase.database().ref('/friends');
....
getFriendsList() {
  let friendsUID = [];
  this.friendsNode.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    let allFriends = snapshot.val();
    this.myFriends = [];
    for (var i in allFriends)
      friendsUID.push(allFriends[i].uid);

    this.userService.getallusers().then((users) => {
      this.myFriends = [];
      for (var j in friendsUID)
        for (var key in users) {
          if (friendsUID[j] === users[key].uid) {
            this.myFriends.push(users[key]);
          }
        }
      this.events.publish('friends');
    }).catch((err) => {
      alert(err);
    })

  })
}
```